# How to export a branch name i.e. env.BRANCH_NAME even after a merge to a target branch in multibranch pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, cicd

I'm trying to use an individual branch to kick off another pipeline with the help of a feature branch, but I'm unable to get an output (env.BRANCH_NAME) after merging a feature branch with a development branch.

I tried to use it as a global variable and export it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to take the latest branch is been merged to target branch

git branch --merged master | tail -2 | head-1